# employee call in and give trip information to be saved in database

Tags: database, ibm-watson

I would like to code something up where my employees can call in and Watson will ask them the important questions, and they can just tell Watson the information and Watson then output that information into a CSV, XLS or etc. format possibly even a database.

It seems that I should be able to do this because of the way it can converse with people through messenger etc.

I know it is probably a 3 pronged approach.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

@Florentino DeLaguna, in this case, you can use Conversation Service and Text to Speech and Speech to text API's from IBM Watson. See options you can use for that:

1. In theory, you would have to built an application that integrates with one URA (using Asterisk for example), convert the Speech to Text, send that text for Conversation Service, and the `response` of the Conversation you would have to transform into *voice* and send to the `URA` . In practice, there are some conversational problems, especially from *Speech to Text*. But the return voice you can use some **effects** using the **IBM Watson Text to Speech** (faster and slower voices, control of pauses, put emotions ...).

Obs.: The URA audios are in *narrowband*, `8khz`, and most *Speech to Text* services only accept *broadband*, `16khz`.

Obs II.:  You app (like Asterisk) need to be able to consume a REST API and / or make use of Web Sockets then it will be able to invoke the Watson Speech to Text service.

2. Another option is to route a call out of Asterisk to the new IBM Voice Gateway which is a SIP endpoint that fronts a Watson self-service agent by orchestrating Speech To Text, Text To Speech and the Watson Conversation service. You can think of IBM Voice Gateway as a stand alone, Cognitive IVR system. Go here for more [details](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4U29/welcome_voicegateway.html).
3. Another potential option is to use `MRCP`. IBM has a services solution that will allow you to reach the Watson STT and TTS engines using MRCP. Not sure if Asterisk supports MRCP but that is typically how traditional IVRs integrate with ASRs.

**Important**: The options 2 and 3 are answered for another person, see the official [answer](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/373747/ibm-watson-with-asterisk.html).

**See more about these API's:**

- [Speech to Text](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/index.html)
- [Text to Speech](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/index.html)
- [Conversation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the Voximal solution, it integrates all the SpeechToText Cloud API (and TextToSpeech) as an Asterisk application throw a VoiceXML standard browser.

All is integrated in the VoiceXML interpreter, you got the full text result of the transcription, and you can push it to a chatbot to detect the intent of the users and pick dynamic parameters like date, number, city, and more... for example by using api.ai.

Voximal supports the STT from Google, Microsoft, IBM/watson (and soon Amazon).

The 3 API listed by Sayuri are embedded in the solution.